# Is there a standard managed switch configuration protocol?

Tags: networking, switch, ethernet

is there a vendor-independend managed switch configuration protocol e.g. for creating VLANs that can be run over TCP or serial port?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. With the right constraints, e.g. Cisco gear and willingness to add Extensible Network Controller (XNC), some features of software defined networking (SDN) might be applicable.

Answer (score 11):

There is no single protocol for managing switches or other network devices. There are a few systems which allow a single management interface, which is then translated into the native configuration for the device (hopefully with some degree of fidelity); but these are neither standardizes or widely deployed.

Comment: ...and here is the case that a short answer wont be downvoted, flagged, destructed, deleted, killed, banned for the eternity! But it gets even 3 upvotes! Yeah!

Comment: @PeterHorvath If you'd like to take up discussion on what you like (or don't like) about serverfault, please do so over on meta.SF. Ranting in comments on main isn't going to do you (or anyone else) any good.

Comment: Feel free to downvote, flag, etc as you see fit. Also feel free to write your own long answer, I'd be glad to throw an upboat on a good answer.

Comment: No. Just... no.

Comment: @ChrisS No, I also upvoted it - sometimes a short answer is okay, and this is a such situation. I wish only a similar collective behavior in the cases if these are posted by a beginner.

Comment: @EEAA See my previous comment.